# SQL: Can GROUP BY contain an expression as a field?

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to group a set of dated records by year, when the date is to the day.  Something like:

```
SELECT venue, YEAR(date) AS yr, SUM(guests) AS yr_guests
FROM Events
...
GROUP BY venue, YEAR(date);
```

The above is giving me results instead of an error, but the results are not grouping by year and venue; they do not appear to be grouping at all.

My brute force solution would be a nested subquery: add the YEAR() AS yr as an extra column in the subquery, then do the grouping on yr in the outer query. I'm just trying to learn to do as much as possible without nesting, because nesting usually seems horribly inefficient.

I would tell you the exact SQL implementation I'm using, but I've had trouble discovering it. (I'm working through the problems on http://www.sql-ex.ru/ and if you can tell what they're using, I'd love to know.) Edited to add: Per test in comments, it is probably not SQL Server.

Edited to add the results I am getting (note the first two should be summed):

```
venue | yr   | yr_guests
1       2012   15
1       2012   35
2       2012   12
1       2008   15
```

I expect those first two lines to instead be summed as

```
1       2012   50
```

Comment: Should work fine. With a result row for each `venue,Yr` combination. What is your data? What are your results? How do they differ from what you expected?

Comment: What are the results?  If you want to group just by year, remove `venue` from the `group by` and `select` clauses.

Comment: Try running `select @@version` to find out the version of SQL.

Comment: @JohnGibb Thanks for the tip! Just tried it, but it doesn't want a SELECT without a FROM.

Comment: @Bibliotango *but it doesn't want a SELECT without a FROM* Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: @Bibliotango is Venue and integer or varchar?

Comment: @Bibliotango That would work in SQL Server, so they must be running something else. Sorry :(

Comment: @ta.speot.is I am not sure of the implementation; that is what I was trying to test with select @@version.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter venue and guests are int. date is a datetime which I am trying to boil down to a year for grouping.

Comment: @Bibliotango could be a bug in excersize implementation, try the same at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks for the link to sqlfiddle.com - I expect I'll be spending a lot of time there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works Fine in SQL Server 2008.

See working Example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b0f9/6

Code pasted Below.

**Create The Events Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [Events]
( Venue INT NOT NULL,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Guests INT NOT NULL
 )
```

**Insert the Rows.**

```
INSERT INTO [Events] VALUES
(1,convert(datetime,'2012'),15),
(1,convert(datetime,'2012'),35),
(2,convert(datetime,'2012'),12),
(1,convert(datetime,'2008'),15);
GO

-- Testing, select newly inserted rows.
--SELECT * FROM [Events]
--GO
```

**Run the GROUP BY Sql.**

```
SELECT Venue, YEAR(date) AS yr, SUM(guests) AS yr_guests
FROM Events
GROUP BY venue, YEAR(date);
```

**See the Output Results.**

```
VENUE   YR  YR_GUESTS
1   2008    15
1   2012    50
2   2012    12
```

Comment: So in the general case, the answer is yes, GROUP BY should take YEAR() as an argument just fine. Thanks very much for the demonstration. I'll used the nested hack on my problem site, knowing that in a production environment I can expect the simple way to work.

Answer (score 0):

it depends of your database engine (or SQL)

to be sure (over different DB Systems & Versions), make a subquery

```
SELECT venue, theyear, SUM(guests) from (
    SELECT venue, YEAR(date) AS theyear, guest
    FROM Events
) 
GROUP BY theyear
```

you make a subtable of

```
venue, date as theyear, guest

aaaa, 2001, brother
aaaa, 2001, bbrother
bbbb, 2001, nobody
... and so on
```

and then

count them